# Unity 3D WebGL Build Error (il2cpp.exe did not run properly!)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl, il2cpp

I want to create and publish my Unity project with WebGL, but I'm getting such an error, I couldn't find the solution even in the unity community, can you help?

I don't know much about using the site and I use translation sorry if I did something wrong

[İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTOwb.png)

Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe" --convert-to-cpp --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="WebGL" --architecture="EmscriptenJavaScript" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\UNİTY\don't touch the lava\Assets /../Temp/StagingArea/Data\Native\build.bc" --cachedirectory="D:\UNİTY\don't touch the lava\Assets..\Library/il2cpp_cache" --compiler-flags="-Oz -DIL2CPP_EXCEPTION_DISABLED=1 " --emit-method-map --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AccessibilityModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AndroidJNIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AnimationModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AssetBundleModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AudioModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ClothModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CoreModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CrashReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DirectorModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DSPGraphModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GameCenterModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GridModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_HotReloadModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ImageConversionModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_IMGUIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputLegacyModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_JSONSerializeModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_LocalizationModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ParticleSystemModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PerformanceReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_Physics2DModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PhysicsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ProfilerModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ScreenCaptureModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SharedInternalsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SpriteMaskModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SpriteShapeModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_StreamingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SubstanceModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SubsystemsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TerrainModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TerrainPhysicsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TextCoreModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TextRenderingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TilemapModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TLSModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UIElementsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UmbraModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UNETModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityAnalyticsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityConnectModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityTestProtocolModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestAssetBundleModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestAudioModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestTextureModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestWWWModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VehiclesModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VFXModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VideoModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VRModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_WebGLModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_WindModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_XRModule_Dynamic.bc" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory="D:/UNİTY/don't touch the lava/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="D:/UNİTY/don't touch the lava/Temp/StagingArea/Data/il2cppOutput"

stdout:
Building build.bc with EmscriptenToolChain
Output directory: D:\UN�TY\don't touch the lava\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native
Cache directory: D:\UN�TY\don't touch the lava\Library\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 99 of which compiled: 0
Total compilation time: 147 milliseconds.
Response file: C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Temp_921101117\response.rsp
Response file: C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Temp_1071019388\response.rsp
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe" -E "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc" -o "D:\UN�TY\don't touch the lava\Library\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A9F5F0C7DDACCF5BF93D3C84FA6CF9DC\build.bc" -s TOTAL_MEMORY=384MB -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -s WASM=0 -O3 "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AccessibilityModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AIModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AndroidJNIModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AnimationModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AssetBundleModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AudioModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ClothModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CoreModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CrashReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DirectorModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DSPGraphModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GameCenterModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GridModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_HotReloadModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ImageConversionModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_IMGUIModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputLegacyModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_JSONSerializeModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_LocalizationModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ParticleSystemModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PerformanceReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_Physics2DModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PhysicsModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ProfilerModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ScreenCaptureModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SharedInternalsModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SpriteMaskModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\l

Comment: Get rid of the ' in the folder name

Comment: @BugFinder it didn't work